# Word for drinks in French

Tags: oral

J'avais une conversation avec un ami. Il m'a dit un truc genre "je suis sorti something something tole.".

J'arrive à comprendre qu'il est sorti hier soir à Paris pour boire mais j'ai pas capté le mot tole. Je lui ai demandé le sens de ce mot et apparemment le mot s'écrit "tole". Après, j'ai cherché partout sur Internet l'usage de ce mot sans y arriver. Quelqu’un peut m'aider avec une explication et un exemple ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas de "**T** [hé]", mais pour un mot qui rime avec "tôle", il y a ["gnôle/gnole/gniôle/gniole/gniolle/gnaule/gniaule/niaule/niôle"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gnole), pour dire " Eau-de-vie, généralement très forte."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il doit probablement s'agir de la phrase argotique:

> Je me suis pris une taule

qui signifie à l'origine je me suis pris une raclée, une branlée, une défaite cuisante mais est aussi utilisé pour dire que l'on s'est pris une cuite, s'est saoulé.

Answer (score 0):

Ou bien l'argot "Je me suis mis une chistole"

Comment: Possible, mais pourrais-tu expliquer ce que veut dire *chistole* ? C'est un argot très particulier et le mot n'est pas dans la plupart des dictionnaires.